# Is it possible to disable required checkout for a specific file in SharePoint library?

Tags: check-out, sharepoint-library

I would like to disable the required checkout for only one folder/file in a SharePoint library that has both, 'version history' and 'required checkout' options on.

Does any of you know if that's possible and know how to do it?

Comment: As Swiss Dev told, there is no way to do it. move those files to a different library and disable versions on it.

Answer (score 3):

Whether or not Checkout is required has to be activate/de-activate on the list itself. It's not possible to do that on each individual file or folder.

I would recommend to move such files to a specific library that does not use mandatory check-out (but still uses versioning).